# How to create PDFOutline programmatically

Tags: python, pdf, quartz

I'm having trouble trying to create Table of Contents objects in a PDF file. I'm not sure whether I've understood the process from Apple's limited documentation.

I'm using python, but cogent examples in any language are welcome to explain how it's supposed to work. The code creates a new PDF document, but there's no outline item visible in Preview. I've tried just using myOutline as the root object, but that doesn't work either.

```
pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(infile)
myPDF = Quartz.PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
if myPDF:
    # Create Destination
    myPage = myPDF.pageAtIndex_(1)
    pagePoint = Quartz.CGPointMake(0,0)
    myDestination = Quartz.PDFDestination.alloc().initWithPage_atPoint_(myPage, pagePoint)

    # Create Outline
    myOutline = Quartz.PDFOutline.alloc().init()
    myOutline.setLabel_("Interesting")
    myOutline.setDestination_(myDestination)

    # Create a root Outline and add the first outline as a child
    rootOutline = Quartz.PDFOutline.alloc().init()
    rootOutline.insertChild_atIndex_(myOutline, 0)

    # Add the root outline to the document and save
    myPDF.setOutlineRoot_(rootOutline)
    myPDF.writeToFile_(outfile)
```

EDIT: Actually, the outline IS getting saved to the new file: I can read it programmatically, and it appears in Acrobat as a Bookmark; however, it doesn't show up in Preview's Table of Contents (yes, I checked for the "Hide" thing). If I add another Bookmark in Acrobat, then both show up in Preview.

So I guess that either I'm still doing something wrong which doesn't quite 'finish' the PDFOutline data properly, and Acrobat is being kind; or there's a massive bug in PDFKit that means you can't write PDFOutlines properly. I get the same behaviour on Mountain Lion, FWIW.

Comment: Can you upload one of these misbehaving PDFs somewhere and add a link?

Comment: I'm not convinced it's the PDFs that are the problem. Acrobat, PDFPen and Foxit Reader all show the 'bookmarks' created with the script. Preview doesn't show them. If you modify the bookmark list in any of those apps, then the items show in Preview. Anyway, here you go: 4 blank pages with one Bookmark. Note that what everyone else calls Bookmarks, Preview calls Table of Contents. Preview's Bookmarks seem to be entirely proprietary and undocumented in the Quartz APIs..!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4gkq8wv51vr6zji/qwe.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug in Preview. It will not list the Table of Contents if it contains ONLY ONE child entry.

If I add more Outlines with the code above, then **all of them** appear in Preview. If use other software to remove **all but one** entries in the Table of Contents, then Preview will not show **any**.